# If my class is a literal class then is it redundant to declare an object of my class as constexpr?

Tags: c++, oop, constexpr

I have a constexpr class Debug:

```
struct Debug {
  constexpr Debug(bool a, bool b, bool c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
  bool a, b, c;
  constexpr bool get() const { return a; }
};

int main() {
  Debug dbg(true, false, false); // is dbg constexpr object?
  constexpr Debug dbg2(0, 0, 0); // is constexpr redundant here?
}
```

As you can see `dbg` is a constexpr object because it is initialized with a constexpr constructor so if I qualify it by a constexpr what is the point in that?

- I don't know the difference between `dbg` and `dbg2`. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference here. It could make a difference if `Debug` had some fields.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `Debug` had three `bool` members. I'll add that back in.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: `dbg` can call non-consexpr member functions while `dbg2` can only call `constexpr` methods.

Comment: @Maestro I think it's not about the methods being `constexpr`, but rather `const`-qualified.

Comment: As a note, a `constexpr` function can be called at both compile time and run time, while a `constexpr` object is guaranteed to exist (as a constant) at compile time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a major difference: only `dbg2` can be used where a constant expression is required. As an example, consider the upcoming C++20 feature that allows arbitrary non-type template parameters:

```
template <Debug> void f() { }
```

With the above definition, `f<dgb2>()` will compile, while `f<dgb>()` will not.

```
f<dgb>();
```

> ```
> <source>:7:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> <source>:13:12: error: the value of 'dbg' is not usable in a constant expression
>    13 |   foo<dbg>();  // ERROR
>       |            ^
>
> <source>:10:9: note: 'dbg' was not declared 'constexpr'
>    10 |   Debug dbg(true, false, false); // is dbg constexpr object?
> ```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1l8CtJ)

---

This is also significant in C++11. You will be able to say:

```
template <bool> void g() { }
g<dgb2.a>();
```

But not:

```
g<dgb.a>();
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jHmyOk)

Comment: OK. Thanks. got it.

Comment: One last question: So does this mean I cannot declare `constexpr` object of non-literal class?

Answer (score 4):

Simple demonstration of how the two variables are different:

```
struct Debug {
  constexpr Debug(bool a, bool b, bool c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
  bool a, b, c;
  constexpr bool get() const { return a; }
};

int main() {
  Debug dbg(true, false, false); // dbg is not a constant
  constexpr Debug dbg2(0, 0, 0); // constexpr makes this a constant expression

  // *** Begin demo ***
  dbg.a = false;
  //dbg2.a = false; //< error: assignment of member 'Debug::a' in read-only object
  // *** End demo ***
}
```

The value of `dbg` can be changed, while the value of `dbg2` cannot.

To get a `Debug` object that is a constant expression, you need both the `constexpr` qualifier in the constructor (to allow a `Debug` object to be flagged as a constant expression) and the `constexpr` qualifier in the variable declaration (to flag that object as a constant expression).